# How do I make a script which always runs in the linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, git, terminal, gnome-terminal

For example, if you install git and type `git` in the terminal, the git program  will respond with an output, no matter what directory you are in. Let's say I make a python script - how can I make it respond to `!test`, for example, without having to run my program and only be able to use the program and no other commands? I understand I have done a bad job at explaining this, but I hope it's clear enough. Thanks

Edit1: I'm not sure if this helps, but I'm running Xubuntu.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Answer (score 1):

You would add the scripts directory to your path variable.

For example, I have a `scripts` directory in my home directory.

I add a path entry to my `.bashrc` like so:

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/scripts`

Then invoke the script within the scripts directory by its filename.

Use `#!` at the top of the script file to provide the path to the binary you want to execute the script with.

- Python: `#!/bin/python`
- Bash: `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc`. And change the file permission to allow execution `chmod 765 path/to/script/file`. Some prefer `700` instead.